# How can I insert line breaks into fields in Crystal Reports without HTML?

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I am creating letter forms and (surprise) there's a handful of line breaks. I want to do this without creating a new field for each paragraph. Set the text interpretation to HTML", but the execution of line breaks is pretty sloppy.

```
dim someText as string

someText = "<p>This is some text " + {dbField} + " followed by some more text.</p>" + _
     "<p>The text continues, but it doesn't create a space between the paragraphs. So I have to do something sloppy like this:</p>" + _
     "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
     "<p>And now I'm assured there is a line break between the two paragraphs.</p>"

formula = someText
```

Is there a cleaner way to do:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: If you mean the fact that you need to concatenate them using a "+", then no, there's no cleaner way. You don't need the underscore though, what is it for?

Comment: The "+ _" at the end of each line is to allow for a line break within the code to enhance readability of the code. That's all.

I'm referring to the <p>&nbsp;</p> code. In some places I have to insert three or four of them. I would think there would be a cleaner way of doing that.